# versioning and deployment of application configuration files to server

Tags: jenkins, web-deployment, visualsvn

We use visual svn for version control. I have few cloud web servers where my websites are running.

I would like to create some repositories for the websites content. I checkout them in local editors (notepad ++), edit them and checkin to SVN. But when check-in to visualSVN, I would like them to get deployed to the webservers docroot. In some cases I would like to restart the webserver too.

Is it possible using Jenkins+deployment plugins. I am very new to jenkins, can somebody help me with some information how we can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

It is one of the scenarios Jenkins is designed for (Continuous Delivery, aka. CD). Your perfect plan might look like this:

1. Get a new instance of Jenkins up/running (for experiments) (if you're familiar with Docker [it is one of the best ways](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/getting-started/installing/#docker) to experiment with Jenkins);
2. Configure [Subversion Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin) in Jenkins (integration with SVN);
3. Setup your first FreeStyle job in Jenkins that polls your Visual SVN server for changes (things you check-in to SVN) and learn how that works (* * * * * <~-
   this polls changes from your source control an every minute, great for experiments);
4. Setup your second FreeStyle job that connects to one of your webservers (probably via SSH) and creates a file (simple "touch hello_world.log" is great to start with) in a special folder dedicated for that kind of tests (**DO NOT MESS WITH YOUR PRODUCTUION CONTENT FOLDER(s)**);
5. Setup your third FreeStyle job that combines your experiences acquired in #1 and #2, and still writes to a test folder;
6. Compare results of the job output with your production deployment expectations (eq. files in place, content is processed the right way, configuration files are looking good and etc.);
7. Try it out on one of the production web servers, one folder/site at a time;
8. Apply your newly crafted delivery pipeline to the rest of servers/sites;
9. Learn how backup your Jenkins instance and actually make your first backup;
10. Try to restore your Jenkins instance from the backup made in the previous step;
11. Decide whether it is okay for you to maintain your own Jenkins instance or you will be better off with a hosted version of it ([CloudBees Inc.](https://www.cloudbees.com/));
12. Learn more about [Pipeline in Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) and possibly (because it is not immediately obvious) migrate your FreeStyle job(s) to [Pipeline DSL](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/)
    and/or [Jenkinsfile](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/);

At times you might need to get back to "[Get Started with Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/doc/)" manual and look up for the ideas or answers, it is okay - do not give up and feel free to post your questions here, at SO.

Hope these ideas will help you to get started.